# ATmega16 Timerr Fast PWM

Tags: pwm

I tried to set up my ATmega16 timer0 for fast PWM. I uset the code form this page:

[ATmega16 Timer Fast PWM](http://www.electronicsplanet.ch/mikrocontroller/avrcodesammlung/atmega16timer0fastpwm.htm)

It works, but the explanations on the page are not so good. Why is the dutycycle 25% if i set OCR0 to 64?

Answer (score 3):

The `OCR0` register controls the duty cycle. Since it's an 8-bit microcontroller, it deals (internally, at least) with 8-bit values. As such, the register has a range of 0 (0% duty cycle) to 255 (100% duty cycle). This is simply a design choice that allows for simple translation of internal values to real values, with a resolution high enough for general purpose.

If you do the math on a range of 256, setting it to 64 gives you 25%, setting it to 128 would give you 50%, and setting it to 192 would give you 75%.